# Is there a C++ equivalent to objective-c's -debugDescription method for Xcode 7?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, llvm

In Objective-C you can add a method called -debugDescription to your classes that return a string.  The Xcode debugger will call this method to display the value of the class in the debugger.  Is there an equivalent to this in C++?

Comment: Do you want to get the name of the class as a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (not with the functionality that the plain language provides). C++ has no so called root object compared to Objective-C's `NSObject` (or `NSProxy`). For such metainfo/introspection/reflection you have to use libraries like [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) or others that support such features.

Answer (score 0):

While not as universal, you can add your own description methods to certain classes of interest and `po` the method at runtime from the console.

E.g.

```
std::string your_class::desc()
{
    return "test";
}
```

```
(lldb) po ((your_class*)0x000000010072adf8)->desc()
"test"
```